# How to file tableview from firebase title folder Xcode

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a question regarding how to file a tableview in Xcode from the liste of folder's title which is all contain in one firebase folder.

Graphical explanation of my firebase structure :

```
Database 
    Main folder 
       Title1
           info1
           info2
           info3
       Title2
           info1
           info2
           info3
       Title3
           info1
           info2
           info3
```

Now I want to make a table view which show to the user only :

```
Title1
Title2
Title3
```

Until today I only know how to extract the liste inside each `Title` But I don't know how to get only the title.

My current code :

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let ev = ref.child("UserSaves").child(uCode)
    ev.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        let flightKey = snapshot.key

        ref.child("UserSaves").child(self.uCode).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            //Here I need to run my request ... 

            //Normally I make a research via the Name of my object, here an exemple where title take the value of the line Auto_Id 

            /*let title = value?["Auto_Id"] as? String ?? "no autoId"*/

            self.datas.insert(Ligne(titre: <#T##String#>), at: 0)

            self.tableView.reloadData() 
        }
    })
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading data through the Firebase SDK will always *read* complete nodes. There is no way through the SDK to just get the keys, without getting the underlying nodes.

But to *use* only the key of each child snapshot, you can use just `snapshot.key`.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
let ev = ref.child("UserSaves").child(uCode)
ev.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    let flightKey = snapshot.key
    self.datas.insert(Ligne(titre: flightKey))

    self.tableView.reloadData() 
})
```